# how to scroll the page to bottom whenever the page load?

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Requirement-**  I want to scroll the content to the bottom of the page whenever the page load.

Here is my html code

```
<ion-content  style="background-color: #f5f8fa;">
  <p style="line-height:24px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:20px;text-transform:capitalize;font-size:16px;">{{this.TASKDESC}}</p>
 <ion-list *ngFor="let list of list; let i = index;" style="margin:0;height:auto;padding-top:5px;padding-left:17px;z-index:-1">


    <ion-item text-wrap class="item" style=" margin-top:-25px;padding:0; background-color:#f5f8fa;z-index:-1;">
      <div [style.margin]="list.TAG_FROM === loggedinuser ? '0px 0px 0px -12px':'0px -12px 0px 0px'" [style.float]="list.TAG_FROM === loggedinuser ? 'right':'left'" style="width:33px;height:33px;background-color:#818993;overflow:hidden;color:#fff;z-index:9.9999999;border-radius:50%;font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding-top:7px;" >{{list.TAG_FROM.substring(0,2)}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Current position of the page**

[image]

**What i want-**  The image of the page

[image]

Scroll to bottom automatically whenever the page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this below code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

...

export class ScrollToBottom {

  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  constructor(){}

  ionViewDidLoad()
  {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
     }, 1000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why is scrollToBottom always accepted in these cases? It's a terrible user experience to always see the list scroll every time you enter the view. There has to be a way to generate the view with the list view already set to the bottom.

Comment: For anyone that struggled like I did.. the `setTimeout` is actually important.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to set the `scrollDownOnLoad` property to true on the `ion-content`.

```
<ion-content scrollDownOnLoad="true">

</ion-content>
```

Find the official documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties)

Answer (score 3):

use the `#content` identifier to obtain a reference to `<ion-content>` using the ViewChild.

```
<ion-content #content style="background-color: #f5f8fa;">
  <p style="line-height:24px;padding-left:10px;margin-top:20px;text-transform:capitalize;font-size:16px;">{{this.TASKDESC}}</p>
 <ion-list *ngFor="let list of list; let i = index;" style="margin:0;height:auto;padding-top:5px;padding-left:17px;z-index:-1">


    <ion-item text-wrap class="item" style=" margin-top:-25px;padding:0; background-color:#f5f8fa;z-index:-1;">
      <div [style.margin]="list.TAG_FROM === loggedinuser ? '0px 0px 0px -12px':'0px -12px 0px 0px'" [style.float]="list.TAG_FROM === loggedinuser ? 'right':'left'" style="width:33px;height:33px;background-color:#818993;overflow:hidden;color:#fff;z-index:9.9999999;border-radius:50%;font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding-top:7px;" >{{list.TAG_FROM.substring(0,2)}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Now use the `this.content.scrollToBottom` to scroll bottom.

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'chatPage.html'
})
export class ChatPage {
  @ViewChild('content') content:any;

  constructor() { }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This `#content` identifier is what I have missed. Works super cool in Ionic 5

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution for this a long time. All these solutions are not good enough since it start with the top of the page and jump to the end. I want it to be load directly to the end. I just find the answer [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-page-already-scrolled-at-bottom-chat-app/77634/4)

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last">
      {{item}}
      {{last ? callFunction() : ''}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and from here this is for ts file:

```
export class Page2 {
  public items: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.items[i] = i
      }
    }, 300)
  }
  callFunction(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
}
```

go the the link to see more on that